# Count elements from a table with differents conditions in mySql?

Tags: mysql

I wanna count all the orders a user has and all the complete orders a user has. I came with this but it´s not working

```
select
    count(a.id) as total,
    count(b.id) as complete
from
    user
join
    orders a on user.id = a.user_id
join
    orders b on user.id = b.user_id
where
    a.id = 1
and
    (b.id = 1 and b.complete = 'yes');
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you include the schema of the tables and some sample of data? Note that when you doing `where a.id = 1` you are restricting to a unique row of table `orders`.

Comment: 1) "Not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. It does not give us any useful information whatsoever. Tell us precisely what the issue is - e.g. error or unexpected results or whatever. 2) Since we have no idea what your tables look like, we can't really tell you what query to write. A sample of the table  data and your expected result would also make it a lot faster for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could sum the order with yes  and count the distinct id  group by user

```
    select user.id, sum(if(a.complete ='yes',1,0)), count(distinct a.id)
    from user
    INNER join orders a on user.id = a.user_id 
    group by user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are searching for grouping ([MySQL GROUP BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)) by the differents users, and then count all the orders related to each user plus the completed ones. For this approach, you will need to:

**(1)** Join users with they orders.

**(2)** Use `GROUP BY` clause on `user.id` column.

**(3)** Count all orders related to each user with `COUNT()`

**(4)** Sum all orders related to each user *having some specific condition* with `SUM(CASE WHEN <specific_condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

In summary, a query like next one should work:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    COUNT(o.id) AS total_orders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.complete = "yes" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS complete_orders
FROM
    user AS u
INNER JOIN
    orders AS o ON o.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
    u.id
```